# VS2008 Project to VS2012 upgrade fails

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2012, project, upgrade, leptonica

Hello i want to build the leptonica library with vc 11 so i downloaded [this leptonica vs2008 project](http://www.leptonica.com/source/vs2008-1.68.zip)

and tried to open it with my vs2012, the solution was starting upgrade with message:

```
One-way upgrade
Visual Studio will automatically make functional changes to the following projects in order to open them. You will not be able to open these projects in the version of Visual Studio in which they were originally created.
     - liblept168, "C:\Lept\vs2008-1.68\vs2008\leptonica.vcproj"
     - ioformats_reg, "C:\Lept\vs2008-1.68\vs2008\prog_projects\ioformats_reg\ioformats_reg.vcproj"
     - leptonica, "C:\Lept\vs2008-1.68\vs2008\leptonica.sln"

No changes required
These projects can be opened in this version of Visual Studio without changing them. They will continue to open in Visual Studio 2010 SP1 and in this version of Visual Studio.
     - prog_files, "prog_files"
     - prog_projects, "prog_projects"
     - Regression Test, "Regression Test"
     - Test, "Test"
     - Utility, "Utility"
     - liblept Helper, "liblept Helper"
     - Example, "Example"
     - ByType, "ByType"
     - ByFilename, "ByFilename"
     - ByCategory, "ByCategory"
     - Exploration, "Exploration"
     - Basic Box, Boxa and Boxaa Functions, "Basic Box, Boxa and Boxaa Functions"
     - Basic Image Operations, "Basic Image Operations"
     - Basic Pix Array Functions, "Basic Pix Array Functions"
     - Basic Pix Functions, "Basic Pix Functions"
     - Colormap Utilities and Related Operations, "Colormap Utilities and Related Operations"
     - Connected Components in Binary Images, "Connected Components in Binary Images"
     - Formatted IO, "Formatted IO"
     - Fundamental Data Structures for Computation, "Fundamental Data Structures for Computation"
     - Image Display, "Image Display"
     - Image Morphology, "Image Morphology"
     - Image Operations With Filling, "Image Operations With Filling"
     - Image Quantization, Depth Conversion, "Image Quantization, Depth Conversion"
     - Image Scaling, "Image Scaling"
     - Line Graphics and Special Output, "Line Graphics and Special Output"
     - Low-level Pixel Access, "Low-level Pixel Access"
     - Misc, "Misc"
     - Other Geometric Image Transformations, "Other Geometric Image Transformations"
     - Postscript, "Postscript"
     - Printing, "Printing"
     - Specialized Document Image Processing, "Specialized Document Image Processing"
     - Specialized Image Filters, "Specialized Image Filters"
```

and after it's passed all the project files, the solution was loaded, but 2 projects was failed to load with following errors:

**Leptonica:**

```
leptonica.vcproj: The item type 'None' is not supported by this project item provider. Parameter name: itemType
Error   leptonica.vcproj: Project upgrade failed.
Warning leptonica_versionnumbers.vsprops: Attribute 'ProjectType' of 'leptonica_versionnumbers' is not supported in this version and has been removed during conversion.
Warning leptonica_versionnumbers.vsprops: Attribute 'Version' of 'leptonica_versionnumbers' is not supported in this version and has been removed during conversion.
Warning leptonica.vcproj: VCWebServiceProxyGeneratorTool is no longer supported. The tool has been removed from your project settings.
Warning leptonica.vcproj: Attribute 'Detect64BitPortabilityProblems' of 'VCCLCompilerTool' is not supported in this version and has been removed during conversion.
Warning leptonica.vcproj: Attribute 'Detect64BitPortabilityProblems' of 'VCCLCompilerTool' is not supported in this version and has been removed during conversion.
Warning leptonica.vcproj: Attribute 'Detect64BitPortabilityProblems' of 'VCCLCompilerTool' is not supported in this version and has been removed during conversion.
Warning leptonica.vcproj: Attribute 'Detect64BitPortabilityProblems' of 'VCCLCompilerTool' is not supported in this version and has been removed during conversion.
```

**and - ioformats_reg:**

```
prog_projects\ioformats_reg\ioformats_reg.vcproj: The item type 'None' is not supported by this project item provider. Parameter name: itemType
Error   prog_projects\ioformats_reg\ioformats_reg.vcproj: Project upgrade failed.
Warning prog_projects\ioformats_reg\ioformats_reg.vcproj: VCWebServiceProxyGeneratorTool is no longer supported. The tool has been removed from your project settings.
```

also
**..\vs2008\leptonica.vcproj:**

```
Error:  The following error has occurred during XML parsing: File: C:\Lept\vs2008-1.68\vs2008\leptonica.vcproj Line: 1069 Column: 0 Error Message: 
Parameter is incorrect. The file 'C:\Lept\vs2008-1.68\vs2008\leptonica.vcproj' has failed to load.
```

**..\ioformats_reg\ioformats_reg.vcproj:**

```
Error : The following error has occurred during XML parsing: File: C:\Lept\vs2008-1.68\vs2008\prog_projects\ioformats_reg\ioformats_reg.vcproj 
Line: 376 Column: 0 Error Message: Parameter is incorrect. 
The file 'C:\Lept\vs2008-1.68\vs2008\prog_projects\ioformats_reg\ioformats_reg.vcproj' has failed to load.
```

I looked up into leptonica.vcproj but on the line 1069 there's just empty space, it's a last line in the file and it's empty. Also i did not found any "itemType" string in this file. Same with the file ioformats_reg.vcproj.

How can i fix this Errors?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error of this:
"The item type 'None' is not supported by this project item provider. Parameter name: itemType"

And, in my case, if I removed all """ from .vcproj files, it solved the problem.

I don't know if it's same case but hope it can be a clue.

Best,